Stored procedure is returning an empty result in Java with JPA
I'm trying to call a stored procedure in the same way I did for other stored procedure, but now I'm having some troubles because it returns a cursor in addition. The return is an empty Map<String, Object> without any type of error, and obviously on the DB the call works well.
Service where I call the repository:
public SpCertifDirittoMIMResult certificazioneDirittoSP(String cf, Date dataInizio, Date dataFine) {
    Map<String, Object> result = certDirDateMIMRepository.certificazioneDirittoSP(cf, dataInizio, dataFine);

    Integer codice = (Integer) result.get("CODICE");
    String messaggio = (String) result.get("MESSAGGIO");
    
    SpCertifDirittoMIMResult response = new SpCertifDirittoMIMResult();
    response.setCODICE(codice);
    response.setMESSAGGIO(messaggio);
    response.setOUT_RS((List<?>) result.get("OUT_RS"));
    
    return response;
}

Repository:
package it.inps.pbgca.certif.diritto.mim.repository.certificazionediritto;

import it.inps.pbgca.certif.diritto.mim.model.entity.certificazionediritto.VwCertifDirittoCFMIM;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Repository
public interface CertDirCFMIMRepository extends JpaRepository<VwCertifDirittoCFMIM, String> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<VwCertifDirittoCFMIM> {
    @Query("SELECT vdp FROM VwCertifDirittoCFMIM vdp ")
    List<VwCertifDirittoCFMIM> findAllCustom();
    List<VwCertifDirittoCFMIM> findVwCertificazioniDirittoMIMByCodiceFiscaleEquals(String codiceFiscale);
    
    @Procedure(name = "CertificazioneDiritto")
    Map<String, Object> certificazioneDirittoSP(
            @Param("PAR_CF") String PAR_CF, 
            @Param("data_inizio_par") Date data_inizio_par, 
            @Param("data_fine_par") Date data_fine_par
            );

}

Class that contains the definition of the stored procedure:
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "CertificazioneDiritto",
            procedureName = "PERLAPPL.DBK_PERL_MS00891.BDP_POSIZIONE_ASSICURATIVA",
            parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "OUT_RS", type = void.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "CODICE", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "MESSAGGIO", type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "PAR_CF", type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "data_inizio_par", type = Date.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "data_fine_par", type = Date.class)
            })
})
@Entity
@Table(schema = "PEDBA", name = "VW_RL047_POSAZZ")
@Data
@Immutable
public class VwCertifDirittoCFMIM implements Serializable {

This rest of this isn't important because the return object is just a Map<String, Object>.
The stored procedure:
PROCEDURE BDP_POSIZIONE_ASSICURATIVA(
    OUT_RS              OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, 
    CODICE              OUT NUMBER,
    MESSAGGIO           OUT VARCHAR2,
    PAR_CF in           char, 
    data_inizio_par     date,
    data_fine_par       date) is 
begin 
    CODICE              := 0;
    MESSAGGIO           := 'OPERAZIONE EFFETTUATA';
OPEN OUT_RS FOR
    SELECT 
    ( select AN007.AN007_CODF_FISCALE from VW_AN007_PERSONAFIS AN007 where  AN007.AN007_ID_PERSONAFIS = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK ) AN007_CODF_FISCALE,
    ( select AN007.AN007_NOME_PERSFIS from VW_AN007_PERSONAFIS AN007 where  AN007.AN007_ID_PERSONAFIS = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK ) AN007_NOME_PERSFIS,
    ( select AN007.AN007_COGNOME_PERSFIS from VW_AN007_PERSONAFIS AN007 where  AN007.AN007_ID_PERSONAFIS = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK ) AN007_COGN_PERSFIS,
    ( select TO_CHAR(AN007.AN007_DATA_NASCITA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA_NASCITA from VW_AN007_PERSONAFIS AN007 where  AN007.AN007_ID_PERSONAFIS = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK ) DATA_NASCITA,--                AN007.AN007_COGNOME_PERSFIS,
            CASE
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_RLTSV_COD_STATO = 'NDP' THEN ' '
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'O' THEN 'OD'
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'Q' THEN 'Q1'
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'M' THEN 'PA'
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'N' THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'P' THEN 'OD'  --OD 2023
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'R' THEN 'Q3'  --PAF 2023
            WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'S' THEN 'OD'  -- OD 2024
            --WHEN RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ IS NOT NULL AND RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'L' THEN 'PA'
            WHEN RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR = 'L' THEN 'PV'   --- AGGIUNTA CONDIONE IL 26-02-2021 FRISCIA
            ELSE  RLTRN.RLTRN_COD_ESITOMIUR
            END AS TIPOLOGIA_PENSIONE,
            DECODE(RLVDP.RLVDP_PERC_MAGGIORAZIONE, 0, '', REPLACE(TRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_PERC_MAGGIORAZIONE, '9,990.00')),'.',',')) AS PERC_MAGGIORAZIONE ,
            LTRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_NUM_ANNIUTILI,'00')) || '*' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_NUM_MESIUTILI, '00')) || '*' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_NUM_GGUTILI, '00')) AS ANZIANITA_CESS,
            LTRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_ETA_ANNICESS, '00')) || '*' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_ETA_MESICESS, '00')) || '*' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_ETA_GGCESS, '00')) AS ETA_ANAG_CESS,
            (select AP023.AP023_DESCL_CONTRATTO || ' - ' || AP020.AP020_DESCL_INQUADRAM 
            from VW_AP023_CONTRATTO AP023
            INNER JOIN VW_AP020_INQUADRAM AP020 ON (AP023.AP023_ID_CONTRATTO = AP020.AP020_COD_CONTRATTO) 
            where (AP020.AP020_ID_INQUADRAM = RLVDP.RLVDP_BDIQ_ID_VA) ) AS CONTRATTO_QUALIFICA ,
                        RLVDP_RLTSV_COD_STATO,
            RLTSV.RLTSV_DESCR_STATO,
            TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_CESSAZ, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA_CESSAZIONE,
                    NVL(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_RAGGREQ, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '') AS DATA_RAGG_REQ,  
                    NVL(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORR, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), NVL(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '')) AS DATA_DECORRENZA,
                    NVL(TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_DECORRFORZ, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '') AS DATA_DECORRENZA_FORZ,
                    REPLACE(NVL(RLVDP.RLVDP_NOTE_TESTO, ''), CHR(13)||CHR(10), ' ') AS NOTE_OPERATORE,
            TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_VERIFICA, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') AS DATA_ORA_VERIFICA ,
                RLILL.RLILL_RLISP_COD_ISTANZA
                FROM
            PEDBA.TB_RLVDP_VERDIRPENS_CL RLVDP
            --INNER JOIN VW_AN007_PERSONAFIS AN007 ON (AN007.AN007_ID_PERSONAFIS = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK ) --AND AN007_CODF_FISCALE = 'CLDRTI57A55A662X')
            --INNER JOIN VW_AP020_INQUADRAM AP020 ON (AP020.AP020_ID_INQUADRAM = RLVDP.RLVDP_BDIQ_ID_VA)
            --INNER JOIN VW_AP023_CONTRATTO AP023 ON (AP023.AP023_ID_CONTRATTO = AP020.AP020_COD_CONTRATTO)
         --   INNER JOIN TB_RLILL_ISCRLISTALAV_CL RLILL ON (RLILL.RLILL_RLLIS_COD_LISTA_PK = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_COD_LISTA_PK
            INNER JOIN TB_RLILL_ISCRLISTAMIM_CL RLILL ON (RLILL.RLILL_RLLIS_COD_LISTA_PK = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_COD_LISTA_PK
            AND RLILL.RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK = RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK
            AND RLILL.RLILL_ANNO_PK = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_ANNO_PK
            AND RLILL.RLILL_ANNO_PK = 2024 )
            INNER JOIN PEDBA.TB_RLLIS_LISTALAVORO_CT ON RLILL_RLLIS_COD_LISTA_PK = RLLIS_COD_LISTA_PK
            INNER JOIN PEDBA.TB_RLTSV_TIPOSTATOVER_CT RLTSV ON (RLTSV.RLTSV_COD_STATO_PK = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLTSV_COD_STATO)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN PEDBA.TB_RLTRN_TIPRICNORM_CT RLTRN ON (RLTRN.RLTRN_NOPRE_COD_NORMAPREST_PK = RLVDP.RLVDP_NOPRE_COD_NORMAPREST
                 AND RLTRN.RLTRN_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR_PK = RLILL.RLILL_RLTDM_COD_TIPDOMIUR)    -- AGGIUNTA CONDIONE IL 26-02-2021 FRISCIA
            WHERE RLVDP_FLAG_STATO = 'A' 
            AND TO_CHAR(RLVDP.RLVDP_DATA_VERIFICA, 'YYYY') <= 2024
            
            --and exists (select AN007.AN007_CODF_FISCALE from VW_AN007_PERSONAFIS AN007 where  AN007.AN007_ID_PERSONAFIS = RLVDP.RLVDP_RLILL_BDPS_ID_VA_PK 
              --          AND AN007_CODF_FISCALE = PAR_CF
                --        ) 
                        --and RLVDP_DATA_DECORR  between data_inizio_par and data_fine_par
                        ;                
end;

This works on the DB, so it's perfectly OK. I don't want and I can't edit this.
I tried lot of alternative, but for my project I need to use JPA with this "style".
